# Is multithreading required when client and server want to talk at the same time?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, client-server, posix

I have two questions regarding using sockets for client server communication.  Assume there is only 1 client in both the cases.

1) I know that we can send and receive data between client and server using a single socket.  But in that case, what will happen when both the server and the client try to send the data at the same time?

2) Which of these is the best model?
    i)   Using single thread, single socket for sending and receiving
    ii)  Using 2 threads(one for sending and one for receiving), single socket
    iii) Using 2 sockets and 2 threads, one for sending and one for receiving.

Comment: What protocol are you speaking between the sockets? TCP/IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question number one, nothing special will happen. TCP is fully duplex, both sides of a connection can send simultaneously.

And as there is no problem with sending/receiving simultaneously, the first alternative in your second question is going to be the simplest.

Comment: Thanks.  Will there be any performance improvement if I use 2 threads and 2 sockets?

Comment: @linuxfreak Probably not, most likely the other way around.

Comment: @ Joachim: Sorry.. I don't get this concept. Suppose, both the machines try to talk at the same time, won't it be faster when i use 2 threads and 2 sockets? Could you explain how the performance lags when i use more than 1 thread? Could you point me to some article that would help me understand when to use multiple threads/sockets?

Comment: @linuxfreak When you have two threads, the processor must switch between them all the time. Even on a modern multi-core processor it still may take time to switch context. Also, your threads have to be synchronized which also will lower performance. And of course there is the added code complexity. Really, many servers can handle hundreds of connections in a single thread, doing both input and output and checking for new connections. Writing a server which only handles one single connection is _very_ simple using a single thread.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So, when should I go for threads?

Comment: @linuxfreak It very much depends. If your server has to be able to handle multiple concurrent connections, but the connections don't have to communicate between each other then threads _might_ be a good idea. Or if you have thousands of connections, then you can have multiple threads, each thread handling multiple connections. Or have one thread handle connections, and another doing something else (file I/O, GUI, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The connection is full-duplex, meaning that sends and receives can happen at the same time. So in answer to question one, both client and server will be able to send/read data from their socket simultaneously.

In terms of which "model" is best, it depends on your application and what you're trying to achieve. Incidentally, you don't *need* to multi-thread. You could:

- Multi-process (fork)
- Use non-blocking sockets (select/poll)
- Use asynchronous notification (signals)

All of which have pros and cons.

Answer (score 2):

In that scenario you dont need threads. The sockets themselves buffer the incoming data until you read it from the file-descriptor. More precisely there are multiple levels of buffers starting at the hardware. You will not *miss* data because you were writing at the same time, it just waits for you until you next read from the socket's file-descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** inherent need for multithreading if you want to poll at multiple sockets.
All you really have to do is use `select()`.

To achieve this you define a `FD_SET` (File-Descriptor Set) to which you add all the sockets you want to poll. This `set` you hand to `select()` and it will return you all file descriptors with pending data.

man page for [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), [fd_set](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set) and a [select tutorial](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut)